# Firefox Addon SDK: Can't trigger click event on document element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox addon using the SDK and I'm having trouble trigger click events on elements within a page.

I'm using the SDK page-mod module as well as jQuery. Stripped down to the scope of this issue, I have the following:

```
/* main.js */

var self = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "http://example.com/*",
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    contentScriptFile: [
        self.data.url("jquery.js"),
        self.data.url("myScript.js"),
    ]
});

/* myScript.js */

$(document).on('click', '#target', function() {

    var buttons = $('button'); // get all buttons on the page

    if(buttons.length) {

        buttons.each(function() {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        });

    }

});
```

The problem is when I click the `#trigger` element on the page, the JS executes fine until it gets to the following line:

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

Then the following error is thrown:

> Permission denied to access property 'length' `jquery-2.1.1.js:4330`

So it seems that the addon is not able to send a click event from itself to the page. Any ideas how to solve this?

Edit: for reference here is a small block of the relevant code in the jQuery source:

```
// Native handler
handle = ontype && cur[ ontype ];
if ( handle && handle.apply && jQuery.acceptData( cur ) ) {
    event.result = handle.apply( cur, data ); // line 4330
    if ( event.result === false ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is always to replace jQuery with pure JavaScript (which executes faster too), here is how you can rewrite `myScript.js` to do so:

```
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"); // get all buttons on the page
    if(buttons.length) {
        for (var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          buttons[i].click();
        }
    }
});
```